# jQuery selector to obtain li object from specific unordered list

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to obtain a specific li element from a unordered list.

I'm doing it this way:

```
var listItem = $('ul.selectedItems').filter(list[i].ID);
```

Any idea of why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` method takes a regular jQuery selector, so you should be writing `filter("#"+list[i].ID)`.  (Assuming that `list[i].ID` is the `id` attribute of an `li` element).  Also, the `filter` method searches the elements contained in your jQuery object, not their children; you should be calling the `children` method instead.  See the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing).

---

However, the best way to do it is like this:

```
var listItem = $('ul.selectedItems li#' + list[i].ID);
```

For more information on jQuery selectors, see [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 1):

This returns only the ul, your selector should return li's

```
var listItem = $('ul.selectedItems li').filter(list[i].ID);
```

But if you have the li's id you can do this

```
var listItem = $('#' + liId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
  $("ul.selectedItems li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).is('#mypreferedid')) {
       //do something here
       return false; //to stop cycling
    }
  });
```

If you don't know the id of the element, but you know it's position you can do this:

```
  $("ul.selectedItems li").each(function(index, element){
    if (index == selectedPosition) {
       //do something here
       return false; //to stop cycling
    }
  });
```